# how to access array inside object without keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, chart.js

I have a JSON data which look like this:

```
 {
  "chart":[
     [
        1627776011000,
        28
     ],
     [
        1627776371000,
        38
     ],
     [
        1627776731000,
        48
     ],
     ...
    ]
}
```

I want to use this data in Chart.js where `1627776011000 ...`  are `x` axis values and `28 ...`  are `y` axis values.

I know I can do it with an array `push`

```
const myArr = JSON.parse(dataJSON);

const data = []; 
const labels = [];

myArr.chart.forEach((item) => {
    labels.push(item[0]);
    data.push(item[1]);
});
```

but could there be a better way, for example with a `map`?

Comment: You could use `reduce`, but the way you do it is just fine. Try not to look for the "perfect" solution, it is much more practical to settle with a working solution.

Comment: What do you mean by "better"? Opinion-based questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as two calls to `map()`:

```
const labels = myArr.chart.map(el => el[0]);
const data = myArr.chart.map(el => el[1]);
```

Comment: thank you. perfect! Would you know roughly how much faster is this than array push from question?

Comment: maybe slower since it has to do two loops. But maybe faster because it can allocate the result arrays at once instead of growing incrementally. You'll need to profile it.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to me like an invented problem.

If your data points are just x and y values, there's nothing wrong with saying the first array element is x and the second is y.

There are some people who would argue and say you should make it an Object with properties like `xValue` and `yValue`.

However, any upsides or downsides in either case would be marginal. You could imagine someone saying the Object version is more readable. The Object version is harder to optimize by the javascript runtime (V8 at least): https://v8.dev/blog/elements-kinds

Unless you have measured it, and it matters, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.reduce()` in as follows:

```js
const myArr = {
  "chart":[
     [
        1627776011000,
        28
     ],
     [
        1627776371000,
        38
     ],
     [
        1627776731000,
        48
     ]
    ]
};

const [labels, data] = myArr.chart.reduce((acc,cur) => [
    [...acc[0], cur[0]],
    [...acc[1],cur[1]]],
[[],[]]);
console.log( labels, data );
```